# jQuery/JS graphs - Plot different colored lines depend on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, graph

I have needed line graph library which supports multi color (most probably three colors) for a mobile application.

Ex: y-axis called Glucose and range of 50 -600, then x-axis date, rage of one month (so always range will be 30 points per day)

Logic: consider x-axis start from

```
1st and level of glucose is 70
2nd  - 80
…
…
…
9th  - 300
10th – 350
…
…
…
15th – 500
16th – 550
…
…
…
25th – 120
26th – 130
```

So my graph should be drawn as follows, depend on the glucose level.

```
50 – 150  - low – and line color should be green
151 – 300 – average – line color should be orange
Above 301 – high – line color should be red
```

I went through Google Graphs, and jqPlot but seems to unlucky, Anyone experience on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finaly, I found excellent lib which was solved my issues. called [Flot Chart](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)

By assigning threshold value and the logic, we can get different colors to same continue line. There are few examples can be found [here](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/).